# Why am I receiving this error-no module named STRINGIO when trying to connect to MYSQL DB using sshtunnel

Tags: python, ssh, airflow, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to connect to my MYSQL database through a SSH tunnel; however I keep receiving errors- mo module named stringIO.

Here is my code:

```
import pymysql
import paramiko
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from paramiko import SSHClient
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from os.path import expanduser
import paramiko
import StringIO    

    import pymysql
    import paramiko
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from paramiko import SSHClient
    from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
    from os.path import expanduser
    import paramiko
    import StringIO


    my_key = """
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    content
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

    """

    pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(StringIO.StringIO(my_key))
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname='my_ip_address', username='my_username', pkey=pkey)

    ssh.close()
```

I have literally tried everything and would highly appreciate if anyone had any suggestions or ideas as to why I am receiving this error.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, the `StringIO` class has been moved into the `io` module. So, try:

```
import io

io.StringIO(my_key)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO.

Comment: NOW i am getting an error of paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: base64 decoding error: Incorrect padding. Do you know why this may be?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with paramiko, so take everything I say with a grain of salt. Googling your error brought up this potential lead: https://gist.github.com/perrygeo/ee7c65bb1541ff6ac770. Try taking a look at that.

Comment: @Coder123 if you've gotten past the original problem and hit a different problem, you should ask a new question.